# Webpack multiple vendor bundles

Tags: javascript, webpack-2, commonschunkplugin

What I'm trying to achieve with webpack is to have 1 core vendor bundle for stable dependencies (react, etc.) and one more vendor bundle for other staff.

I could create one huge vendor bundle with filtering via minChunks.

```

```
   new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
     name: ['vendor'],
     minChunks: ({ resource }) => /node_modules/.test(resource)
   }),
```

```

[image: Bundles stats]

But when it comes to creating multiple vendor bundles with same strategy (filtering modules via minChunks) webpack either duplicates deps across bundles or throws `While running in normal mode it's not allowed to use a non-entry chunk`.

[image: dublicates]

I know that it is possible to list all deps in entries and use for all of them `minChunks: Infinity` but then there are still some some libs from node_modules appear in app code.

It would be very useful at least to know how to **exclude** modules from app entry